# How can I add data to an existing PowerPoint presentation using Node?

Tags: node.js, powerpoint, ms-office

I have a PowerPoint template with placeholder data. I need to swap out the placeholder text with some numbers using Node, but I'm having trouble finding a package that supports this. Has anyone seen anything along these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the [PowerPoint JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/powerpoint-add-ins-reference-overview)?

For example:

1. Call the `ShapeCollection.getItem(key)` method to get your `Shape` object
2. Update the text value via `Shape.textFrame.textRange.text`

Related example from [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/shapes#text-in-shapes):

```
// This sample creates a light blue rectangle with braces ("{}") on the left and right ends
// and adds the purple text "Shape text" to the center.
await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const shapes = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0).shapes;
    const braces = shapes.addGeometricShape(PowerPoint.GeometricShapeType.bracePair);
    braces.left = 100;
    braces.top = 400;
    braces.height = 50;
    braces.width = 150;
    braces.name = "Braces";
    braces.fill.setSolidColor("lightblue");
    braces.textFrame.textRange.text = "Shape text";
    braces.textFrame.textRange.font.color = "purple";
    braces.textFrame.verticalAlignment = PowerPoint.TextVerticalAlignment.middleCentered;
    await context.sync();
});
```